# Can't able to change the values inside iframe using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" id='frameID' height="200" width="300"></iframe>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var iFrameDOM = $("iframe#frameID").contents();

    iFrameDOM.find("body").css("background-color", "blue!important");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to change the background color of the body inside iframe,its not working at all.,which is taken from w3schools...Run and check in that.

Comment: `blue!important` => `blue`

Comment: The iframe content you are using, is it on the same domain?

Comment: yes,it's on w3schools

Comment: @pranav-->Thanks,but its not working

Comment: iframe take from other websites(w3school.com) and used in your website(xyz.com) won't work. They must be on the same domain to make the work.

Comment: @rahul i'm working on the same website and the iframe content is also from the same domine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the iframe hasn't loaded yet when you call its contents. So do the job after iframe loads. 
There are two ways. Firstly, you can remove `!important` and it will work fine.

**1st way:**

```
$(function(){
    var $iframe = $("iframe#frameID");
    $iframe.on('load', function(){
        var iFrameDOM = $iframe.contents();
        iFrameDOM.find("body").css("background-color", "blue");
    });
});
```

**2nd way:**
But if you need to add `!important`, you have to do this with a class:

```
$(function(){
    var $iframe = $("iframe#frameID");
    $iframe.on('load', function(){
        var iFrameDOM = $iframe.contents(); 

        iFrameDOM.find("head").append($("<style type='text/css'>  .bodyBg{background-color:blue!important;}  </style>"));

        iFrameDOM.find("body").addClass('bodyBg');
    });
});
```

**Extra information:**
Below code may not work on some IE versions, you may not be able to select the body:

```
var iFrameDOM = $iframe.contents(); 
var $body = iFrameDOM.find("body");
```

To pass this, simply do this:

Add name attribute to the iframe:

```
<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="frameName" id='frameID' height="200" width="300"></iframe>
```

And select the body with this code:

```
var body = window.frameName.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var $body = $(body);
```

Comment: Thank u,But it's not working.Even i tried with setting up the interval but it didn't work

Comment: I've changed the code, tested it on my local and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('iframe').load( function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find("head")
      .append($("<style type='text/css'>  .my-class{display:none;}  </style>"));
});
```